# $rootScope and $scope, shared object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an angularjs app, i define in a controller `$scope.pimp.init`, and in other controller `$scope.pimp.panels`, so, what i must put to init pimp : `$scope.pimp= {};` or `$rootScope.pimp = {};` , in the angular run starting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how it can be implemented using services.

Service:

```
myApp.service('pimpService', [function () {
    return {
        pimp: {
            init: null,
            panels: null
        }
    };
}]);
```

Controllers:

```
myApp.controller('ctrl1', ['$scope', 'pimpService', function ($scope, pimpService) {
    pimpService.pimp.init = 'foo';
};

myApp.controller('ctrl2', ['$scope', 'pimpService', function ($scope, pimpService) {
    pimpService.pimp.panels = 'bar';
};
```